# Mysql get latest record of each group where pk and date are different

Tags: mysql

I have table with following columns

- pk - bigint - primary key
- timestamp - int(11)
- id - int(4)
- some extra columns

id + timestamp can be duplicate

I want to get latest record of each id in single query

Currently I run following query for each item id

```
select data.* from (
select pk from data 
    where 
     id = 1001
     order by timestamp desc, pk desc
     limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select d.*
  From data d
 Where d.pk in ( select max(d2.pk)
                   From data d2
               Group by d2.id, d2.timestamp
                )
```

Comment: I have around 900k data where there are 30 id, so it takes forever to run this query.